# jQuery If Then else Statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

how would I would I write

```
If (margin-top for #ted = 100px)
then
(.animate #ted margin- top: 20px)
else
(.animate #ted margin- top: 50px)
```

Can this be done and if so can you show me how? Thank You for all the help!

Comment: Ok I tried and fail I no know what I do wrong

Comment: What did you try? Can we see your jQuery code?

Comment: @eric2872 is O_O your other account? It's looks too suspicious that your last ~8 questions was answered by this guy and all of them contained no code but only one sentence: http://gyazo.com/0b2fbda818cdf14e18930c4fd750ded0
Are you trying to raise reputation?

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this:

```
var ted = $('#ted');

if (ted.css('margin-top') === '100px') {
    ted.animate({'margin-top' : '20px'});
}
else {
    ted.animate({'margin-top' : '50px'});
}
```

Good luck!